# Setting the values ​of a COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, count, sas

I'm using SAS and I'm stuck when I want to relay this in SQL :

I have a column that counts the number of line repetitions :

```
DUPLICATES | NUMBER   |  DATE
---------------------------------
 2         |  123     |  22-05
 2         |  123     |  22-05
 3         |  222     |  21-05
 3         |  222     |  21-05
 3         |  222     |  21-05
 1         |  111     |  23-05
 ...
```

Code :

```
CREATE WORK.TABLE TABLE_TEST AS
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES,
          NUMBER,
          DATE
   FROM WORK.INITIAL_TABLE
   GROUP BY NUMBER, DATE;
```

I would like to block the result of the `COUNT(*)` so that when I do a `SELECT DISTINCT...` on the table, I only have one row per value but with its initial number of repetitions :

```
DUPLICATES | NUMBER   |  DATE
---------------------------------
 2         |  123     |  22-05
 3         |  222     |  21-05
 1         |  111     |  23-05
 ...
```

I tried to make a copy of the `DUPLICATES` column but it also copied the calculation method `COUNT(*)` which gives me a bad result when I do a `SELECT DISTINCT` :

```
DUPLICATES_V2 | NUMBER   |  DATE
---------------------------------
 1            |  123     |  22-05
 1            |  222     |  21-05
 1            |  111     |  23-05
 ...
```

If you have an idea of ​​how to proceed or documentation it would help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  It sounds like you just want the results of your first query.  Explain what you want that is different than that.

Comment: Your first query has a typo, I assume in the create table statement? It looks like you're just looking for a proc freq though. Maybe try that.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. Your code already seems to output what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, IMHO the simplest is proc sort:

```
proc sort data=work.INITIAL_TABLE out=TABLE_TEST nodupkey;
  by NUMBER DATE;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't really help me. I would like to have the number of occurrences of the same line, keep this number, and delete all the duplicates lines to have at the end only the line in question and the number of times it was in the table

Comment: Frankly saying I still do not understand your requirements. Could you please provide a sample input table and the expected output? Then I can try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want PROC FREQ here. I suspect your query isn't as shown and you have another column included, but not in the GROUP BY which is causing your issues. The query as shown has errors and would not successfully run.

```
proc freq data=initial_data noprint;
table number*date / out=want;
run;
```